# macOS document icon template?

Tags: macos, icons

The original question below has been overtaken by time: these days you do not have to supply icons or icon sets for your documents any more, as macOS will generate a standard icon out of your application icon and the system document icon template. See https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=5i6jlf4d This seems a recent development, the document in the link is dated January 2021.

You still have to supply CFBundleDocumentTypes in your plist, to bind the document extension to your application, but leave out CFBundleTypeIconFile that you can use to attach your own iconset to your documents.

**Original question:**
Is there a template available for the Mac OS X document icon? It looks like a white piece of paper with the top right corner curled down. Lots of applications seem to use this icon as a base for their own custom document types. Does everyone use a template for the basic shape, or does every developer have to draw their own from scratch?

I know you can get the plain document icon here:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/GenericDocument.icns
```

But that is in [.icns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format) format rather than a format I can easily edit. Also, it doesn't make it easy if you want the document background to be anything but white.

It would be great if there is a Photoshop (.psd) template available for each icon size (512, 256, 128, 32, 16).

Comment: Preview will open icns files and allow you to save them as png files... which can be easily modified in apps like photoshop. Plus Apple gives us the Icon Composer app to help us make icns files from pngs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about saving as PNG from Preview.

Comment: The problem is in the layers, it would be really nice to have the top-right folded age on a separate layer.

Comment: I found the all the pieces of the generic document icon, at all sizes, in `/System/Library/CoreServices/IconsetResources.bundle/Contents/Resources/Artwork` on macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra). This folder contains separate PNGs for the background, the curled corner overlay, and the transparency mask, for every size from 16x16 to 512x512 in @1x and @2x resolutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several tools, that converts your image (drawn in Photoshop) into an icon-format:

- [Iconeer](http://www.squidoo.com/iconeer)
- [Img2icns](http://www.img2icnsapp.com/)
- [IconBuilder](http://iconfactory.com/software/iconbuilder/)
- [Pic2Icon](http://mac.softpedia.com/progDownload/PicIcon-Download-5734.html) *(seems to be not supported any longer)*
- [FastIcns](http://projects.digitalwaters.net/index.php?q=fasticns)

To convert an icon-format into another graphic-format (so you can easily modify) I can recommend:

- [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/)
- [PhotoLine](http://www.pl32.com/)

Greate sources for free icons are:

- [freeiconsweb](http://www.freeiconsweb.com/)
- [freeiconsdownload](http://www.freeiconsdownload.com/)
- [60 Icon Photoshop Templates](http://speckyboy.com/2010/09/30/60-psd-icon-and-button-templates/)

Please read the licence of the sets you download! You can download a lot of free icons there and reuse them or even modify them. Then you can convert them back into the icon-format with the tools mentioned above.

Comment: Why not just use the Icon Composer app that's included with Xcode?

Comment: @Abhi Beckert because with the Icon Composer you can not create Icons from a jpg, since Icon Composer can not import different image-formats (like jpg) or images that are bigger than 512x512px

Comment: Just yesterday I used Icon Composer to create a 1024x1024 pixel icon using a 2048px source png image. You seem to be right about the jpg though... but I don't know why anyone would create an icon that has no transparency.

Comment: @Erik One shouldn't use JPEGs as input for icons; besides the transparency, it is a compressed format and will introduce noisy looking artifacts from the compression.  Also, you don't need to use anything besides `iconutil` which is included with OS/X and can do both extraction and creation of .ICNS files.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25083332/211160)

Answer (score 15):

You can find various curl images in the QuickLook framework:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/Resources/`

You can then composite your document icon over the generic document icon, which also gives you the mask for the curled page icon:

`/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/GenericDocumentIcon.icns`

Answer (score 8):

You can turn a directory full of .PNG files into an .ICNS or vice-versa using `iconutil`.  It comes with OS/X and is a command-line program:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/iconutil.1.html

You can also use Preview to extract individual PNGs out of the file.  But to extract all the icons from the file you mention with their appropriate labels -- start up a command terminal in the directory where you want your output, and run this command:

> iconutil -c iconset /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/GenericDocumentIcon.icns -o ./GenericDocumentIcon.iconset

If you're going the reverse direction, note that when building an .ICNS the directory you are building it from must end in `.iconset` and the filenames are very specific.  The files in the directory must be named:

- icon_16x16.png
- icon_16x16@2x.png
- icon_32x32.png
- icon_32x32@2x.png
- icon_128x128.png
- icon_128x128@2x.png
- icon_256x256.png
- icon_256x256@2x.png
- icon_512x512.png
- icon_512x512@2x.png

For details on that and what the 2x is about, see [High Resolution Guidelines for OS/X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html)

The default page curl is rather "oppressive", especially at the small sizes like 16x16.  Perhaps it looks good on a blank document icon, but when you're putting an image on it gets in the way.  Document icons I looked at up close at that resolution often soften the gray edge on the curl and generally lighten up the darkness.

For instance, Google Chrome:

[image: chrome icon 16x16 zoomed up]

vs. the default:

[image: default OS/X blank document icon zoomed up]

I point it out just because I think it's a bit of a lost cause to make decent looking document icons at 16x16 if you follow their page curl there verbatim.

Comment: I got really confused about the fact that you double many icon sizes. But sure, when you want different icons (resp. amount of details) for different sizes you'll need that

Comment: @Julian Well, it's all about the user experience I guess.  But to a developer... pain!  I think my answer deserves an upvote, YMMV :-)

Comment: Yes, it does indeed :)

Comment: And your right, I just wanted to add some knowledge resp. my observations ;)

Answer (score 8):

There is [docerator](https://github.com/panicinc/docerator) tool which allows to [image]

Comment: I didn't know about docerator. Thanks for answering this old question.