# Changing mac folder icon with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos

Is it possible to change the icon of a Mac folder using a set of Ruby commands? I believe that OSX requires a .icon file to be present within the modified folder, perhaps there is a specific way of converting a jpg or png to the .icon criteria?

-- Edit (Working solution. Requires ImageMagick and [OSXUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxutils/))
* note, for my application I intended to set folder icons. It is entirely possible this could work for files as well.

```
def set_icon image, folder

        # Convert to absolute paths and setup
        image = File.expand_path image
        folder = File.expand_path folder
        dim = 512
        thumb = folder + '/'+ 'thumb.png' # PNG supports transparency
        icon = folder + '/'+ 'icon.icns'

        # Convert original to thumbnail
        system "convert '#{ image }' -quiet -thumbnail '#{dim}x#{dim}>' \
          -background none -gravity center -extent #{dim}x#{dim} '#{ thumb }'"

        # Set icon format. Causes 'libpng warning: Ignoring attempt to set cHRM RGB triangle with zero area'
        system "sips -s format icns '#{ thumb }' --out '#{ icon }'"

        # Set the icon
        system "seticon -d '#{ icon }' '#{ folder }'"

        # Cleanup
        FileUtils.rm thumb
        FileUtils.rm icon
end
```

Comment: You're just asking if this is possible? Or you've actually tried to do it and couldn't get it to work? See http://SSCCE.org. Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3454201/128421 and the linked questions?

Comment: A little of both. Thanks for providing those links!

Comment: Apparently `iconutil` will convert a folder of suitably named png files into a single icns file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been years since I played with them, but .icon files' format were documented by Apple's documentation and Wikepedia.

If I remember right, the name has a trailing `"\r"` to make it harder to type, but that's easily handled from code.

You should be able to use the normal [`File.rename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-rename) method to move an .icon file into a folder, and the Finder should do the right thing.

---

Looking at your code, I'd do some things differently:

```
require 'fileutils'
def set_icon image, folder

    # Convert to absolute paths and setup
    image = File.expand_path image
    folder = File.expand_path folder
    temp = File.join(folder, 'temp2' + File.extname(image))

    # Copy image
    FileUtils.cp(image, temp)

    # Take an image and make the image its own icon
    system "sips -Z 512 -i #{ temp }"

    # Extract the icon to its own resource file
    system "DeRez -only icns #{ temp } > tmpicns.rsrc"

    # Append a resource to the folder you want to icon-ize
    system "Rez tmpicns.rsrc -o $'#{ folder }/Icon\r'"

    # Use the resource to set the icon.
    system "SetFile -a C #{ folder }"

end
```

Rather than rely on `sprintf` or `%` ("format") to build the strings, instead use simple interpolation. `sprintf` strings are great when you need to force column widths and coerce values into a different representation, but they're overkill when you're inserting a single value that isn't formatted.

`sips` has this option, which looks promising, but it's not documented well in the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html):

```
 -i
 --addIcon
       Add a Finder icon to image file.
```

Also, Stack Overflow's sibling site "Ask Different" has "[Why setting image as its own icon with sips result a blurred icon? Are there any alternatives?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10666/why-setting-image-as-its-own-icon-with-sips-result-a-blurred-icon-are-there-any)", "[How do I set an icon for a directory via the CLI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30882/how-do-i-set-an-icon-for-a-directory-via-the-cli?rq=1) and "[Changing a file or folder icon using the Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/changing-a-file-or-folder-icon-using-the-terminal)" which look useful.